# ES Lint graphQL error - Unexpected Name "ESLintPluginGraphQLFile"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql, eslint

I've inherited a project that uses ESLint with Prettier and i'm getting a compile issue when running ES Lint after opening and editing a GraphQL file. Here's the error message i'm getting:

> Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "ESLintPluginGraphQLFile" (1:1) ESLintP
>
> ESLintPluginGraphQLFile`fragment CfAccordionItem on CfAccordionItem {
>
> trackingTitle
>     title
>      body

The error comes after running this command:

```
eslint --ext .js ./src ./internals --ext .graphql --cache
```

Below is an example of a graphQL file that fails in eslint. If I remove this file then eslint will just fail on the next .graphql file:

```
#import "./page-link.graphql"
#import "./image.graphql"

fragment CfMenuItem on CfMenuItem {
  title
  page {
    ...CfPageLink
  }
  image {
    ...CfImage
  }
  externalLink
  externalUrl
  internalAction
  sys {
    id
  }
}
```

Here are my dev dependecies in my package.json that are related to eslint:

```
"eslint": "^4.4.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.2",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^2.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-compat": "^1.0.3",
"eslint-plugin-graphql": "^1.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "^0.4.0",
"husky": "^0.14.3",
"prettier": "^1.5.3",
"graphql": "^0.10.5",
"graphql-tag": "^2.4.2",
```

Finally here is my eslint configuration settings

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/react',
  ],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    'redux-saga',
    'react',
    'import',
    'jsx-a11y',
    'compat',
    'prettier',
    'graphql',
  ],
  rules: {
    'arrow-body-style': ['error', 'as-needed'],
    'class-methods-use-this': 0,
    'compat/compat': 2,
    'global-require': 0,
    'import/named': 2,
    'import/no-dynamic-require': 0,
    'import/no-named-as-default': 0,
    'import/no-unresolved': 2,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'max-len': [
      'error',
      {
        code: 80,
        ignoreUrls: true,
        ignoreComments: true,
        ignoreStrings: true,
        ignoreTemplateLiterals: true,
      },
    ],
    'new-cap': [
      2,
      {
        capIsNew: false,
        newIsCap: true,
      },
    ],
    'no-param-reassign': 0,
    'no-shadow': 0,
    'no-tabs': 2,
    'no-underscore-dangle': 0,
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        singleQuote: true,
        bracketSpacing: true,
      },
    ],
    'react/forbid-prop-types': [
      'error',
      {
        forbid: ['any'],
      },
    ],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 0,
    'redux-saga/no-yield-in-race': 2,
    'redux-saga/yield-effects': 2,
    'react/jsx-no-bind': [
      'error',
      {
        ignoreRefs: true,
        allowArrowFunctions: false,
        allowBind: false,
      },
    ],
    'react/no-unknown-property': [
      2,
      {
        'ignore': ['itemscope', 'itemtype', 'itemprop']
      }
    ],
    'graphql/template-strings': [
      'error',
      {
        env: 'apollo',
        schemaJson: require('./internals/graphql.schema.json'),
      },
      {
        env: 'literal',
        schemaJson: require('./internals/graphql.schema.json'),
      },
    ],
  },
  settings: {
    polyfills: ['fetch', 'intersectionobserver'],
  },
};
```

I did a bit of research on the error and found [this](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/81):

However upgrading to `eslint-plugin-prettier@2.4.0` didn't help the issue as suggested and besides i'm running a version below that and the post suggests that the issue occurs in version 2.5.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!